# Loop returning last item of array

Tags: javascript, json, express

I am trying to loop through this json object, I want to return the associated points, total and percent for the items inside of 'points'.

The code only outputs >100 which is the last item each time it loops through

```
    <%
     var connection = appdata.cao.years,
        year = null,
        totalStudents = null,
        points = null

        for(var i=0; i < connection.length;i++) {
            year = connection[i].year;
            totalStudents = connection[i].total;
              for(var j = 0; j < connection[i].points.length;j++){
                 points = connection[i].points[j].id;
            }
     %>
        <p>
            <%=year %>,
            <%=totalStudents %>
            <%=points %>
        </p>

    <%}%>
```

And here is the JSON

```
{
"name":"cao json",
"description":"breakdown of cao statistics",
"cao":{
    "id":1,
    "years":[
        {
            "id":"1",
            "year":"2015",
            "total":"55045",
            "points":[
                {
                    "id":"2",
                    "points":"600",
                    "total":"215",
                    "percent":"0.4"
                },
                {
                    "id":"3",
                    "points":"500-599",
                    "total":"5431",
                    "percent":"9.9"
                },
                {
                    "id":"4",
                    "points":"400-499",
                    "total":"14097",
                    "percent":"25.6"
                },
                {
                    "id":"5",
                    "points":"300-399",
                    "total":"14446",
                    "percent":"26.2"
                },
                {
                    "id":"6",
                    "points":"200-299",
                    "total":"9768",
                    "percent":"17.7"
                },
                {
                    "id":"7",
                    "points":"100-199",
                    "total":"6562",
                    "percent":"11.9"
                },
                {
                    "id":"8",
                    "points":" >100",
                    "total":"4526",
                    "percent":"8.2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":"9",
            "year":"2014",
            "total":"54025",
            "points":[
                {
                    "id":"10",
                    "points":"600",
                    "total":"162",
                    "percent":"0.3"
                },
                {
                    "id":"11",
                    "points":"500-599",
                    "total":"5088",
                    "percent":"9.4"
                },
                {
                    "id":"12",
                    "points":"400-499",
                    "total":"13447",
                    "percent":"24.9"
                },
                {
                    "id":"13",
                    "points":"300-399",
                    "total":"14047",
                    "percent":"26"
                },
                {
                    "id":"14",
                    "points":"200-299",
                    "total":"9584",
                    "percent":"17.7"
                },
                {
                    "id":"15",
                    "points":"100-199",
                    "total":"6926",
                    "percent":"12.8"
                },
                {
                    "id":"16",
                    "points":" >100",
                    "total":"4771",
                    "percent":"8.8"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":"17",
            "year":"2013",
            "total":"52767",
            "points":[
                {
                    "id":"18",
                    "points":"600",
                    "total":"152",
                    "percent":"0.3"
                },
                {
                    "id":"19",
                    "points":"500-599",
                    "total":"4813",
                    "percent":"9.1"
                },
                {
                    "id":"20",
                    "points":"400-499",
                    "total":"12803",
                    "percent":"24.3"
                },
                {
                    "id":"21",
                    "points":"300-399",
                    "total":"13381",
                    "percent":"25.4"
                },
                {
                    "id":"22",
                    "points":"200-299",
                    "total":"9566",
                    "percent":"18.1"
                },
                {
                    "id":"23",
                    "points":"100-199",
                    "total":"6914",
                    "percent":"13.1"
                },
                {
                    "id":"24",
                    "points":" >100",
                    "total":"5138",
                    "percent":"9.7"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":"25",
            "year":"2012",
            "total":"52589",
            "points":[
                {
                    "id":"26",
                    "points":"600",
                    "total":"165",
                    "percent":"0.2"
                },
                {
                    "id":"27",
                    "points":"500-599",
                    "total":"5026",
                    "percent":"9.6"
                },
                {
                    "id":"28",
                    "points":"400-499",
                    "total":"12395",
                    "percent":"23.6"
                },
                {
                    "id":"29",
                    "points":"300-399",
                    "total":"13170",
                    "percent":"25"
                },
                {
                    "id":"30",
                    "points":"200-299",
                    "total":"9588",
                    "percent":"18.2"
                },
                {
                    "id":"31",
                    "points":"100-199",
                    "total":"6999",
                    "percent":"13.3"
                },
                {
                    "id":"32",
                    "points":" >100",
                    "total":"5276",
                    "percent":"10"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":"33",
            "year":"2011",
            "total":"54341",
            "points":[
                {
                    "id":"34",
                    "points":"600",
                    "total":"162",
                    "percent":"0.3"
                },
                {
                    "id":"35",
                    "points":"500-599",
                    "total":"4863",
                    "percent":"8.6"
                },
                {
                    "id":"36",
                    "points":"400-499",
                    "total":"12235",
                    "percent":"22.5"
                },
                {
                    "id":"37",
                    "points":"300-399",
                    "total":"13860",
                    "percent":"18.4"
                },
                {
                    "id":"38",
                    "points":"200-299",
                    "total":"9966",
                    "percent":"18.4"
                },
                {
                    "id":"39",
                    "points":"100-199",
                    "total":"7477",
                    "percent":"13.8"
                },
                {
                    "id":"40",
                    "points":" >100",
                    "total":"5928",
                    "percent":"10.9"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":"34",
            "year":"2010",
            "total":"54480",
            "points":[
                {
                    "id":"35",
                    "points":"600",
                    "total":"136",
                    "percent":"0.2"
                },
                {
                    "id":"36",
                    "points":"500-599",
                    "total":"4564",
                    "percent":"8.4"
                },
                {
                    "id":"37",
                    "points":"400-499",
                    "total":"11973",
                    "percent":"22"
                },
                {
                    "id":"38",
                    "points":"300-399",
                    "total":"13878",
                    "percent":"25.5"
                },
                {
                    "id":"39",
                    "points":"200-299",
                    "total":"10391",
                    "percent":"19.1"
                },
                {
                    "id":"40",
                    "points":"100-199",
                    "total":"7294",
                    "percent":"13.4"
                },
                {
                    "id":"41",
                    "points":" >100",
                    "total":"6244",
                    "percent":"11.5"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

The code is javascript, wrapped inside of an expressJS tag

Comment: What template are you using `<%= %>`?  That is not JavaScript or JSON.

Comment: Please add more description. What was the error, what you are trying to achieve and such. Also, full code sample isn't required and it makes the post hard to read.

Comment: @DavinTryon I think that is ASP or JSP? Not sure :/

Comment: The template is Ruby.

Comment: @DavinTryon It is expressJS, using it with node js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have variable `points = null` that ressign to every loop iterate, so instead of

```
points = connection[i].points[j].id;
```

you should use

```
points.push(connection[i].points[j].id);
```

and also before change

```
points = null
```

to

```
points = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should extend over the `<p>` tag so that every item will get printed to the page. As of now your whole loop will get executed before the output stage and all previous values are overwritten in the process. So move the closing bracket after the output block.